# Temporarily Disable System.out

Tags: java, constructor, io

I'm trying to implement [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281068/turn-off-the-output-stream) of temporarily disabling outputs of a rogue library. My problem however is that I getting this:

```
The constructor PrintStream(new OutputStream(){}) is undefined
```

With this code

```
 PrintStream out = System.out;
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
                 public void write(int b) throws IOException {}
            }));
```

How can this class not have a constructor? Thanks

Comment: That compiles fine on my system. Try adding `@Override` above `public void write()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually forwarding all system.out and system to the underlying logger.

```
private static void redirectStdOutErrToSl4j() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
        @Override
        public void print(final String s) {
            logger.info(s);
        }
    });
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(System.err) {
        @Override
        public void print(final String s) {
            logger.error(s);
        }
    });
}
```

and simply calling the method on a static block.